# Azure MVnet IR to connect to on-premise Oracle sink

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have to copy data from cloud(Azure SQL database) to on-premise Oracle.
Due to security reasons, I can not use self-hosted IR, need to use Azure Mvnet IR.
I am able to connect to Azure SQL databse which is the source using a managed private endpoint but
Oracle option is not available.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Due to security reasons, I cannot use self-hosted IR, need to use Azure Mvnet IR.

As per this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites)

> **You can use the managed virtual network integration runtime feature in Azure Data Factory to access the on-premises network without installing and configuring a self-hosted integration runtime.**

To do this you need managed virtual network, virtual network on on-prem database and managed VNet enabled data factory.

Steps provided in this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-managed-virtual-network-on-premise-sql-server) using the Azure portal to setup Private Link Service and access on-premises Server from Managed VNet using Private Endpoint. You can similarly create for Oracle database connector.